# C# Nest, Elastic Search: update and add to a field that is a list

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This may be a bit of a dumb question but I'm new to elastic search and nest.

I have a class

```
Person
{
     public string Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public IList<string> PhoneNumbers {get; set;}
}
```

And what I want to do is update the Phone number by adding to it.

Right now I'm doing it with 2 queries but I'm wondering if there is a way I could manage it with 1.

```
        // See if the Person already exists
        var result = NestClient.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Index(_indexName)
        .Take(1)
        .Query(q => q
        .Term(p => p.Name, person.Name)
        && q.Term(p => p.Id, person.Id)));

        if (result.ServerError != null)
        { 
            throw result.OriginalException;

        }
        if (result.Documents.FirstOrDefault() == null)
        {
            var response = NestClient.Index<Person>(person);
            if (response.ServerError != null)
            {
                throw response.OriginalException;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If it does exist update and overwrite
            var savedPerson = result.Documents.First();

            IList<string> oldNums = SavedPerson.PhoneNumbers;
            IList<string> newNums = newPerson.PhoneNumbers;
            var combinedNums = oldNums.Concat(newNums);

            newPerson.PhoneNumbers = combinedNums.ToList<string>();

            var response = NestClient.Update(DocumentPath<Person>
                .Id(newPerson.Id),
                u => u.Doc(newPerson).DocAsUpsert(true));
            if (response.ServerError != null)
            {
                throw response.OriginalException;
            }
        }
```

Basically I want my upsert to add to the existing list of phone numbers if it exists.

Comment: Are you planning to keep duplicate phone numbers? if not use `Union` instead of `Concat`.

Answer (score 3):

If script is an option you can do this with [scripted update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates).

Option with duplicated items after update in array

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, DocumentPartial>(DocumentPath<Document>.Id(1), descriptor => descriptor
    .Script(@"ctx._source.array += tab;")
    .Params(p => p.Add("tab", new[] {4, 5, 3})));
```

and without

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, DocumentPartial>(DocumentPath<Document>.Id(1), descriptor => descriptor
    .Script(@"ctx._source.array += tab; ctx._source.array.unique();")
    .Params(p => p.Add("tab", new[] {4, 5, 3})));
```

Full example:

```
public class DocumentPartial
{ 
    public int[] Array { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public int[] Array { get; set; }
}

var client = new ElasticClient(settings); 

client.CreateIndex(indexName, descriptor => descriptor
    .Mappings(map => map
        .Map<Document>(m => m.AutoMap()))); 

var items = new List<Document>
{
    new Document
    {
        Id = 1, 
        Array = new[] {1,2,3}
    } 
};

var bulkResponse = client.IndexMany(items);

client.Refresh(indexName);

var updateResponse = client.Update<Document, DocumentPartial>(DocumentPath<Document>.Id(1), descriptor => descriptor
    .Script(@"ctx._source.array += tab; ctx._source.array.unique();")
    .Params(p => p.Add("tab", new[] {4, 5, 3})));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to specify on which field property unique() applies to...My issue is when I update using the above script its adding the duplicate record in my nested document. E..gg i have record with _id  = 5 and there is an nested document with car as card Id and Car name, even though there is record with car id = 1 and car name = "test" when i just update the car name as "test2", its adding another record with Car id  =1 and car name  ="test2".. Is there a way to avoid this..Please help

Comment: You can write your custome comperator for unique function, [have a look](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/01/groovy-goodness-removing-duplicate.html).

Comment: Thanks Rob.. but just one more quick. Is there any other way..Can i have for loop in the scripts above and then check with if condition and then update only that document by comparing their Id..Is it Possible?? Sorry for  throwing question but am really stuck and not able to proceed..

Comment: I think [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589963/elasticsearchuse-script-to-update-nested-field) answer will help you.